# Google autocomplete API replacement?

Tags: api, autocomplete, google-api, google-custom-search

I am using this API for the keyword autocomplete
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=xxx

This api is stopped working since August 10th, 2015.
Google suggested us to use CSE instead but CSE seems for us to search the web content, not for auto suggestion.

What service / api should I use if I want to re-enable my "autocomplete" in search box?

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a late reply, but I find it funny that firefox is actually using `https://www.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=somequery` for the search autosuggest on the `about:newtab` page. Though they maybe using a specially crafted header or something to make that work. You can check the requests with the browsertoolbox (regular inspector or firebug won't work).

Google CSE does actually have an autocomplete function, but apparently that only works if you set CSE to show results of sites you specified, not for showing results of the entire internet.
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631081

Currently I'm seeing it works for neither, even after waiting a couple of days for google to create an index for the autosuggest.

If in the meantime you have found a better solution please let me know!